# Using trim() but still didn't get expected output

Tags: java, spring, string

Ok,i am developing spring MVC based web application, application shows data is list, and i also facilitate filter options to enhanced search functionality, I also remove extra space by using trim(), but what happening now, when user input data in text field and enter the corresponding result will be displayed into the list, but if space added after input, the result will be "NOT FOUND" even i handle the space in javascript too

Java Code which fetches data from database

```
 if (searchParamDTO.getRegNO().trim() != null && !searchParamDTO.getRegNO().trim().equals("") && !searchParamDTO.getRegNO().trim().equals("null")) {
                    query += " AND UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID = :REG_UNIQUE_ID ";
                    param.addValue("REG_UNIQUE_ID", searchParamDTO.getRegNO());
                }
```

JavaScript Code: fetches the value in behalf of id

```
function setSearchParameters() {
    regNo = $('#regNo').val().trim();}
```

i also attached two screenshot with spaces and without spaces
[image]

[image]

Without space
With space

Comment: You're trimming the string when checking if it's blank, but then adding the raw string to the query which will include any trailing spaces.

Comment: @GregH You should post it as an answer. Good catch! :)

Comment: @gregH  can you explain in more detail with snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using trim() to remove spaces,but still didn't get expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717292/using-trim-to-remove-spaces-but-still-didnt-get-expected-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Greg H said you're trimming the string when checking if it's blank, but then adding the raw string to the query which will include any trailing spaces.

Then, this line `param.addValue("REG_UNIQUE_ID", searchParamDTO.getRegNO());` should be replaced by `param.addValue("REG_UNIQUE_ID", searchParamDTO.getRegNO().trim());`

Comment: wow thank you so much, now i realize i missed to handle at addalue(), thank you GregH and Raudel